# Values in message structure do not match RFC message structure

Tags: transaction, iota-network, tangle

I'm trying to understand what is the structure of the messages in IOTA. I used scylla to download some messages and now I don't see that the structure from the message matchs with the current one explained in the [RFC 0017](https://github.com/GalRogozinski/protocol-rfcs/blob/message/text/0017-message/0017-message.md#message-structure).

I'm going to use the following message:

https://explorer.iota.org/mainnet/message/fe328724335d3071626adb31274eebdaa11078d5efdc3dfb4c9bbaaae264fd95

If you scroll down and export the mesage in `Hex` format we have the following:

```
 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
```

Now I will try the identify the elements using the previous RFC:

- NetworkID (8 bytes): `b77f44715e0b3014` - OK
- Parents' length (1 byte) : `04` - OK
- Parents (32 bytes x number of parents): - OK

  `06929877c0c305afad2548d31adb9c1e9d1ad7503788a56ad40a50ef6ce435ff`
  `5c77eb6798ac5125c4e82123961aefd463a61e7f598205c461c1af37e9ed50c4`
  `ae3deda4af7b9a5c3c6a0c0a6480d6261283a9805a6e8046a45e5944505041c3`
  `d0040e4ea8c39179982498b9f2115a74750111b734cb823d16d338a9615c57c7`

Here comes the problem:

- Payload Length (Should be 5 bytes): Not sure, but if I get 5 bytes I have: `7300000002`. In my opinion this does not seem to be the payload length, especially considering that the `02` seems to be the payload type...
- Payload Type (Should 5 bytes): Here I know that the payload type is `2` because it it an [Indexation payload](https://github.com/GalRogozinski/protocol-rfcs/blob/message/text/0017-message/0017-message.md#indexation-payload) but it does not match with the bytes from the message. If we get 5 bytes: `0000001100`, and I don't know what is this...
- Index (Should be 1 to 64 bytes long): `7777772e696f74612e777466205350414d` - OK
- Unexpected value (Bytes size unknown): `58000000`. I don't know what is this...
- Data Fields (Any bytes, as we can see in the hex from the message, we have the index here too): `7777772e696f74612e777466205350414d0a436f756e743a203035333035310a54696d657374616d703a20323032312d30352d32385431363a30303a35382b30323a30300a54697073656c656374696f6e3a203338c2b573` - OK
- Nonce (8 bytes): `937a100000000000` - OK

As you can see, we have some elements that are not described or does not match with the specification in the RFC:

- Payload length
- Payload Type
- Unexpected value

Please, has anyone any experience with this? Probably I'm doing something wrong, but I think my explanation is correct.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem as I can see it is that you are interpreting the payload length as 5 bytes, according to spec it is uint32 - so it is 4 bytes. From this point on the data is as follows, which matches the spec.

Payload Length uint32 = 4 bytes

`73000000`

Payload Type uint32 = 4 bytes

`02000000`

Indexation Key Length uint16 = 2 bytes

`1100`

Indexation Key

`7777772e696f74612e777466205350414d`

Indexation Data Length uint32 = 4 bytes

`58000000`

Indexation Data

`7777772e696f74612e777466205350414d0a436f756e743a203035333035310a54696d657374616d703a20323032312d30352d32385431363a30303a35382b30323a30300a54697073656c656374696f6e3a203338c2b573`

Nonce - 8 bytes

`937a100000000000`

Comment: Thank you very much! I can't believe I didn't notice that... Don't know why I was interpreting 5 bytes as uint32...